# Player movement in an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner so please forgive me.
I am trying to make a text based game. I'm having trouble moving the player through the array. 
0 = empty spaces
p = player

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, p, 0, 0]

I want the outcome to be, when i type in 1 the player moves up

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, p, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

but i think my code is displaying it to be

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, p, 0, 0]

[ 0, 0, p, 0, 0]

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    //starting player position
    int px = 4;
    int py = 2;
    String player = "P";

    String map[][] = new String[5][5];

    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {

            map[px][py] = player;

            System.out.println(map[i][j]);

            int move;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            move = scanner.nextInt();

            //up
            if(move == 1) {
                map[px][py + 1] = player;
                printMap(map);
            }

            //right
            if(move == 2) {
                map[px + 1][py] = player;
                printMap(map);
            }

            //left
            if(move == 3) {
                map[px - 1][py] = player;
                printMap(map);
            }

             //down
            if(move == 4) {
                map[px][py - 1] = player;
                printMap(map);
            }

        }

}


public static void printMap(String a[][]) {

    for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for( int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.println( a[i][j]);

        }
```

Comment: You need to reset where the `player` used to be back to `0`, right now you are just copying the `player` instead of swapping.

Comment: You also need to move `map[px][py] = player;` outside of the loops, or you will set the player to his starting position at every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question you just need to set back to zero like:

```
//up
if(move == 1) { 
  map[px][py + 1] = "0";
  map[px][py + 1] = player;
  printMap(map);
}
```

But there are couple of problems with your code:

1. If you want to move **up** then you should substruct one from the row index, same thing for other directions (see my code below).
2. When you declare a String array, it's content will be nulls you should initialized it with zeros (String zeros).
3. See how I printed the 2D array, each row I used `print` instead of `println`.
4. Also you need to update px/ py indexes as @Nexevis mentioned

   see this code example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //starting player position
        int px = 4;
        int py = 2;
        String player = "P";

        String map[][] = new String[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
                map[i][j]="0";
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {

                map[px][py] = player;

                //System.out.println(map[i][j]);
                System.out.println("1-move up \n2-move right \n3-move left\n4-move- down");
                int move;
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                move = scanner.nextInt();

                //up
                if(move == 1) {
                    map[px][py] = "0";
                    map[--px][py] = player;
                    printMap(map);
                }

                //right
                if(move == 2) {
                    map[px][py] = "0";
                    map[px][++py] = player;
                    printMap(map);
                }

                //left
                if(move == 3) {
                    map[px][py] = "0";
                    map[px ][--py] = player;
                    printMap(map);
                }

                //down
                if(move == 4) {
                    map[px][py] = "0";
                    map[++px][py] = player;
                    printMap(map);
                }


            }

    }
    public static void printMap(String[][] a) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < a[1].length; j++) 
                System.out.print( a[i][j]+" ");         
          System.out.println();
        }
   }
}
```

Note that you should add validation for array indexes for preventing IndexOutOfBound Exception

Comment: thank you so much, this was very helpful and i have learnt so much